# Joining one table twice with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have below table A - which has From and To Location.

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | FG |

Below table B - has the Location longitude and latitude

| Zip | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 90 | 80 |
| FG | 45 | 67 |

I want to combine the above two tables to get the below result wherein From Location has latitude and longitude and similarly To Location has Latitude and Longitude.

| From | From_Lat | From_Long | To | To_Lat | To_Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 90 | 80 | FG | 45 | 67 |

Can someone help with the syntax to join table A and table B to get the desired results?

Comment: Have you considered performing a `JOIN` on the value of `From`/`To`  to the column `Zip`? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use two join clauses:

```sql
SELECT [from], f.lat, f.long, [to], t.lat, t.long
FROM   tab_a a
JOIN   tab_b f ON a.[from] = f.zip
JOIN   tab_b t ON a.[to] = t.zip
```

Comment: And the important trick is to use (distinct) aliases ('t' and 'f' here)

Comment: I'm getting invalid table alias A error. below is the query Im using
select from_zipcode,F.latitude as From_Latitude,to_zipcode,T.Latitude as To_Latitude 
from TableA as A
JOIN TableB F on cast(A.From_ZipCode as integer)=cast(F.zip as integer) 
JOIN  TableB T on cast(A.To_ZipCode as integer)=cast(T.zip as integer)

Comment: @AkshayShinde you shouldn't have an `as` between `TableA` as `A`

Comment: @Mureinik - I itried without 'as' as well and its still throwing the same error